# Routing to a specific IP-Address fails while network is fine

Tags: debian, routing, ping, traceroute

This is my first post to Stackexchange so if it lacks any neccessary information I can add this after posting.

---

My problem is that I am trying to reach the api of riot games. I have a Debian-Rootserver hosted at zap-hosting.com.

It was running fine for multiple months now without a single timeout. However, yesterday it stopped working since it could not connect to the euw api of riotgames.

After looking into the issue I found out that the connection is not working and stops somewhere in southkorea. I don't even know why that is the route, it seems kinda overkill - neither I know whether I can change it or not.

I can ping and reach any ip-address from said server besides this specific one (euw1.api.riotgames.com)

Below you can find neccessary information on the issue which is me pinging and tracerouting the address. I talked to my hoster but they said it's out of their area of influence. What can/should I do to get access to euw1.api.riotgames.com (104.160.144.188) again?

[image: Pinging and tracerouting said address]

Text from image:

---

```
root@ # ping euw1.api.riotgames.com
PING rapi.redge.globalriot.aws-rclusterprod-euc1-1.riotapi.rc.pvp.net (104.160.144.188) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 61.43.235.210 (61.43.235.210) icmp_seq=25 Destination Net Unreachable  
From 61.43.235.210 (61.43.235.210) icmp_seq=54 Destination Net Unreachable  
From 61.43.235.210 (61.43.235.210) icmp_seq=64 Destination Net Unreachable  
From 61.43.235.210 (61.43.235.210) icmp_seq=65 Destination Net Unreachable  
^C  
--- rapi.redge.globalriot.aws-rclusterprod-euc1-1.riotapi.rc.pvp.net ping statistics ---  
67 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 527ms  

root@ # ping 61.43.235.210
PING 61.43.235.210 (61.43.235.210) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 61.43.235.210: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=322 ms  
64 bytes from 61.43.235.210: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=318 ms  
64 bytes from 61.43.235.210: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=209 ms  
64 bytes from 61.43.235.210: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=210 ms  
^C  
--- 61.43.235.210 ping statistics ---  
5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 39ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 209.163/264.866/322.044/55.318 ms  

root@ # traceroute euw1.api.riotgames.com  
traceroute to euw1.api.riotgames.com (104.160.144.188), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
 1  * * *  
 2  * * *  
 3  ae6-core4.core3.ffm3.de (45.138.175.61)  5.139 ms  5.161 ms  5.143 ms  
 4  160.20.144.69 (160.20.144.69)  5.286 ms  5.265 ms  5.235 ms  
 5  ae14-2021.fra10.core-backbone.com (80.255.14.5)  5.165 ms  5.151 ms   
 5.137 ms
 6  core-backbone.uplus.co.kr (5.56.19.98)  5.120 ms  5.145 ms  5.117 ms  
 7  1.208.104.217 (1.208.104.217)  179.002 ms  181.657 ms  183.618 ms  
 8  1.208.107.77 (1.208.107.77)  214.308 ms 61.42.0.117 (61.42.0.117)  213.980 ms 1.208.105.141 (1.208.105.141)  216.979 ms  
 9  1.208.104.166 (1.208.104.166)  211.839 ms !N 1.208.104.194 (1.208.104.194)  214.205 ms !N 1.208.104.166 (1.208.104.166)  219.410 ms !N  

root@ # ping na1.api.riotgames.com  
PING rapi.redge.globalriot.aws-rclusterprod-usw1-1.riotapi.rc.pvp.net  (104.160.150.26) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 104.160.150.26 (104.160.150.26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=257 ms  
64 bytes from 104.160.150.26 (104.160.150.26): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=260 ms  
64 bytes from 104.160.150.26 (104.160.150.26): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=256 ms  
^C  
--- rapi.redge.globalriot.aws-rclusterprod-usw1-1.riotapi.rc.pvp.net ping statistics ---  
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 3ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 256.319/257.835/260.417/1.925 ms
```

---

Thanks in Advance for your help!

Fabsi

Comment: The host `euw1.api.riotgames.com` is pingable. Maybe you should check with your internet provider

Comment: It's a rootserver that is hosted from somewhere else. As visible in the image I can ping anything else (so the connection is working). It's just that one address that seems to end in south korea (which I don't know why because both servers are located in the EU). So I don't exactly have an internet provider that I can talk to here

Comment: It would be easier if we knew how that route used to look when it worked.